# How to set proto source directory based on another sub-project's proto source directory?

Tags: gradle, protocol-buffers

The following doesn't work since `test-data-proto-definition` hasn't been configured yet so `sourceSets.main.proto` doesn't exist:

```
sourceSets {
  main {
    proto {
      srcDirs = project(':test-data-proto-definition').sourceSets.main.proto.srcDirs
    }
  }
}
```

The following doesn't do what's intended, either:

```
generateProtoTasks {
    all().each { task ->
        project.sourceSets.main.proto.srcDirs = ["${project(':test-data-proto-definition').projectDir}/src/main/proto" as String]
    }
}
```

What's needed to be able to reference the `proto.srcDirs` of another sub-project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue here is that the sub-project `test-data-proto-definition` hasn't yet been configured. [Configuration time dependencies](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/multi_project_builds.html#sub:configuration_time_dependencies) indicates use of `evaluationDependsOn` should solve the issue. For example:

```
evaluationDependsOn(':test-data-proto-definition')
```